# Finding change in RGB colour channels -Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

My program takes in an image and splits it into a grid (of smaller images), then the mean RGB value is worked out at each window of the grid.

I am trying to work out the difference between the `mean_val` (mean RGB) of a window and the previous window in the sequence, to find the change in colour between neighbouring windows ((x+1) - x) but I am unsure how to implement this.

Here is my code:

```
#import packages
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Read in image
img = cv2.imread('images/0021.jpg')
#print img.shape
scale = 9

#Get x and y components of image
y_len,x_len,_ = img.shape
#cv2.imshow('Original',img)
#cv2.waitKey(5000)

mean_values = []
for y in range(scale):
    for x in range(scale):
        #Crop image scale*scale windows
        cropped_img=img[(y*y_len)/scale:((y+1)*y_len)/scale,(x*x_len)/scale:((x+1)*x_len)/scale]

        mean_val=cv2.mean(cropped_img)
        mean_val=mean_val[:3]

        #set pixel values of each window to the meanBGR
        cropped_img[:,:,:] = mean_val

        #Print mean_values array
        mean_values.append([mean_val])
mean_values=np.asarray(mean_values)
print mean_values.reshape(3,scale,scale)

cv2.imshow('output',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.imwrite('images/BGR_90.jpg',img,[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90])
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the output image of my program:
[image: 9x9 mean RGB]

Thank you for reading and any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: So did you want to find the difference between the previous window in the sequence at the same spatial locations **as well** as those in neighbouring positions?  What did you want to do with these difference windows?  Considering one position in the current frame and the same position in the previous frame, you have 17 possible positions to consider if you add in the neighbourhoods - 8 from the current frame without the target spatial location and 9 from the previous frame with the target spatial location.  Which ones did you want to analyze?

Comment: @rayryeng What I am trying to do is build a basic shadow detector with the idea that where there is a shadow in the scene, the change in texture will be large but the change in colour will be small. For texture I am using variance and for colour I am using meanRGB. So I need to find where in the image this happens and thats what im struggling with. Would I need to look at all 9 surrounding positions or could I just look at the previous position?

Comment: Ah, that depends on how big of a block you're analyzing.  The larger the block, then it may suffice to just look at just the previous position.  However, the smaller the block, then you may need to look at neighbouring positions.  Did you just want to look at the previous block for now?

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah I think if I just look at the previous block for now that would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use this list comprehension before you change `diff_mean` to an array.

```
diff_mean=[[mean_values[i][j]-mean_values[i-1][j] for j in range(3)] for i in range(1,len(mean_values))]
```

Also if `mean_val` is a tuple, you should change `mean_values.append([mean_val])` to `mean_values.append(mean_val)`

**Edit:**
Or if you want to have the differences between each window without the difference between the rightmost window and the leftmost window in the row below, you could do this (after transforming to array):

```
 diff_mean=mean_values[:,:,:-1]-mean_values[:,:,1:]
```

**Edit 2:** updated code to work for a list of 3-element tuples / and also for a 3D array.

Comment: Using your first suggestion I get two floats per array output and I am unsure what they mean. What I want is the difference between the R,G,B channels off the previous window so I can find the change in colour, shouldn't I expect three outputs, one for the difference of each colour channel?

Comment: @NeilVicker I edited the code, hopefully it works now

Comment: I tried what you said, but I still only get 2 outputs. `mean_values` is an array with three elements, one for each colour channel, so I am unsure as to why I am getting 2 outputs.

Comment: Did you change `mean_values.append([mean_val])` to `mean_values.append(mean_val)`?

Comment: I did yes, still gives two outputs

Comment: I changed your answer slightly and now I get the expected output. `diff_mean=mean_values[1:,:,:]-mean_values[:-1,:,:]`.